# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LT01" when expecting one of the following: ( select

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, casting

When I am trying create a following procedure, the following error is occured

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LT01" when expecting one of the following:     ( select
```

The line of a code which is giving error is:

```
lnbuf :=(cast(multiset('LT01' as char(8)) || cast(REC.WN_COUNTRY as char(3)) || cast(rec.WN_NORMSSNR_WW as char(32)) || cast(REC.WN_SOFTWARE as char(7)) || cast(REC.WN_NORMSSNR as char(32)) || RPAD(' ',32,' ') || cast(REC.WN_NAME_WW as char(16)) || cast(REC.WN_NAME as char(16)) || cast(REC.WN_NORMBYTE as char(6)) || cast('0' as char(3)) || cast('ST' as char(2)) || RPAD(' ',70,' ') || cast('ST' as char(3)) || RPAD(' ',60,' ') || to_char(rec.WN_FOD,'YYYYMMDD') || to_char(rec.WN_LOD,'YYYYMMDD')));
```

The above statement is fetching the result from the table mentioned in the below code which also contain some hard coded information and that is being fed into text file (using db.util package).
Casting is used for formatting the rows as I expected.

My Question is:
I ran the same statement with select query in worksheet gives the desired results

```
select (cast('LT01' as char(8)) || cast(REC.WN_COUNTRY as char(3)) || cast(rec.WN_NORMSSNR_WW as char(32)) || cast(REC.WN_SOFTWARE as char(7)) || cast(REC.WN_NORMSSNR as char(32)) || RPAD(' ',32,' ') || cast(REC.WN_NAME_WW as char(16)) || cast(REC.WN_NAME as char(16)) || cast(REC.WN_NORMBYTE as char(6)) || cast('0' as char(3)) || cast('ST' as char(2)) || RPAD(' ',70,' ') || cast('ST' as char(3)) || RPAD(' ',60,' ') || to_char(rec.WN_FOD,'YYYYMMDD') || to_char(rec.WN_LOD,'YYYYMMDD')) from t_wn_ctab_str rec where rec.wn_ctab_id=1234;
```

But if the same statement is substituted in a procedure is throwing compile time  error.

Help me in solving this error!

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE CREATE_CTAB_FILE (f_ctab_id IN T_WN_CTAB_str.wn_ctab_id%type,
                                    P_SYN_DIR in varchar2,
                                    p_user    IN varchar2)

is 
FILEHANDLER WN_DB_UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
LNBUF varchar2(4000) := null;
--cast(lnbuf as char(4000));
--LNBUF clob;

v_file     varchar2(256);
V_DATA_LOG varchar2(256);
V_WN_COUNTRY T_WN_CTAB_STR.WN_COUNTRY%type;
V_H_L varchar2(256);


BEGIN


for CTAB_REC in 
(select distinct WN_COUNTRY, WN_PRHB_DATE
from t_wn_ctab_h 
where wn_ctab_id =f_ctab_id)

loop

v_wn_country:=ctab_rec.wn_country;

--bkk_solution.wn_insert_res_log('create_ctab', NULL, NULL, help_rec.wn_cty, help_rec.wn_vers_sol, 'START', p_cty);

v_file:=v_wn_country||'_CTAB'||'.txt';

fileHandler := WN_DB_UTL_FILE.FOPEN(P_SYN_DIR,V_FILE,'W');
--p_file_id := fileHandler.id;

lnbuf := ('#' || rpad(' ',42,' ') ||'V3.4.5'||rpad(' ',197,' ') ||         '000000000000000000000000000'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')||     to_char(ctab_rec.WN_PRHB_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') ||rpad(' ',48,' ')|| '1');   -- '<html>' -Tag ausgeben
WN_DB_UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, lnbuf);
for REC in
(select STR.C_ID, STR.WN_CTAB_ID, STR.C_CRE_DAT, STR.C_UPD_DAT,     STR.WN_COUNTRY, STR.WN_NORMSSNR_WW, STR.WN_SOFTWARE, STR.WN_NORMSSNR, STR.WN_NAME_WW,
str.WN_NAME, str.WN_NORMBYTE, asm.Unit, str.Wn_Fod, str.Wn_Lod from T_WN_CTAB_STR str, t_wn_res_gerg gerg,t_master_dat asm where str.WN_CTAB_ID = f_ctab_id and WN_COUNTRY=v_wn_country and asm.c_id=gerg.wn_c_id_bke)
LOOP    
lnbuf :=(cast(multiset('LT01' as char(8)) || cast(REC.WN_COUNTRY as char(3)) || cast(rec.WN_NORMSSNR_WW as char(32)) || cast(REC.WN_SOFTWARE as char(7)) || cast(REC.WN_NORMSSNR as char(32)) || RPAD(' ',32,' ') || cast(REC.WN_NAME_WW as char(16)) || cast(REC.WN_NAME as char(16)) || cast(REC.WN_NORMBYTE as char(6)) || cast('0' as char(3)) || cast('ST' as char(2)) || RPAD(' ',70,' ') || cast('ST' as char(3)) || RPAD(' ',60,' ') || to_char(rec.WN_FOD,'YYYYMMDD') || to_char(rec.WN_LOD,'YYYYMMDD'))); 

WN_DB_UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, lnbuf); 
end LOOP;
WN_DB_UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
end LOOP; 
END CREATE_CTAB_FILE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your loop code in the below fashion.

```
DECLARE
   LNBUF   VARCHAR2 (4000) ;
BEGIN
  --Your loop starts
 Loop
   LNBUF   := NULL ;

   SELECT (   CAST ('LT01' AS CHAR (8))
           || CAST (REC.WN_COUNTRY AS CHAR (3))
           || CAST (rec.WN_NORMSSNR_WW AS CHAR (32))
           || CAST (REC.WN_SOFTWARE AS CHAR (7))
           || CAST (REC.WN_NORMSSNR AS CHAR (32))
           || RPAD (' ', 32, ' ')
           || CAST (REC.WN_NAME_WW AS CHAR (16))
           || CAST (REC.WN_NAME AS CHAR (16))
           || CAST (REC.WN_NORMBYTE AS CHAR (6))
           || CAST ('0' AS CHAR (3))
           || CAST ('ST' AS CHAR (2))
           || RPAD (' ', 70, ' ')
           || CAST ('ST' AS CHAR (3))
           || RPAD (' ', 60, ' ')
           || TO_CHAR (rec.WN_FOD, 'YYYYMMDD')
           || TO_CHAR (rec.WN_LOD, 'YYYYMMDD'))
     INTO lnbuf
     FROM t_wn_ctab_str rec
    WHERE rec.wn_ctab_id = 1234;

   dbms_output_put_line (lnbuf);
 End Loop ;
END;
```

Comment: Made changes as below. 
But when I ran the procedure I am getting the below error

    Error report:
    ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
    ORA-06512: at "my_db.CREATE_CTAB_FILE", line 51
    ORA-06512: at line 2
    01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
    *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
    *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Could you please suggest me how I could assign fetched data into a variable?

Comment: This is something not releated to this issue of yours posted earlier..Post it again as a new issue and experts may help you

Answer (score 0):

I Think there is "select" keyword missing after "multiset(" and you will have to give table name as you mention in a select statement.

As you already told it is properly running as individual query.

sample code:-

```
CAST(MULTISET(SELECT ca.street_address,   
ca.postal_code, 
ca.city, 
ca.state_province, 
ca.country_id
FROM cust_address ca
WHERE s.custno = ca.custno)
AS address_book_t)
```

Comment: Tried the suggested changes but still error is persisting
Error is like:
`Error(43,45): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     , from 
Error(43,80): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     ) varying large 
Error(46,40): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     . ( , * % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <an exponent (**)> as    from into || multiset bulk `